# AVFoundation: "Flip camera" button on tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, avfoundation

I'm working on a hobby iPhone app in Swift, aiming to learn a bit of AVFoundation in the process. The app contains 3 view controllers: for the camera view, the photo list view and the login view, all managed by a custom instance of UITabBarController.

I'd like to use one of the tab bar buttons to work as a switch between front and back camera of the iPhone, although I can't figure out a way to do it. If someone more experienced than myself could direct me where to look, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty UIViewController and add it to UITabBar.Then implement UITabBarControllerDelegate to your viewcontroller then use this code:

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController.isKind(of: YourEmptyViewController.classForCoder()) {
            //Do your action (for toggle camera)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!